# How to completely remove MySQL from a windows 7 machine

Tags: mysql, sql, windows-services, uninstall

I'm new to MySQL struggling to find a version and workbench which works stably on my 64 bit windows 7 machine.

I've decided to attempt to completely remove MySQL from my machine and to restart the installation process from scratch.

However, after uninstalling all software linked with MySQL using conventional control panel uninstalling means some MySQL windows services still remain on my machine.

I can't see any obvious method to remove these and they have since been causing me difficulties when trying to install different versions of MySQL.

Could anyone please advise?

Comment: A Ford broke down & a top Microsoft programmer was a passenger. He suggested close all the windows, walk around the car & then open the windows.

Comment: I think the guys over at [DBA SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) may be of more help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a post on superuser which answers my question:

[How to remove MySQL service from windows](https://superuser.com/questions/452262/how-to-remove-mysql-service-from-windows)

To remove the MySQL service run the command prompt as admin then use the following command:

```
sc delete MySQL
```

Where MySQL is the title of the windows service.